# Вытащить значения из тегов html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется подобного вида конструкция:

```
<div class="col-4 productCard" id="pCard15">
<img class="image" src="ссылка">
<h1 class="titleText">123</h1>
<p class="descriptionText">123</p>
<p class="priceText">321$</p>
<button class="btn btn-success changeProduct" id="changeProduct">Change Product</button>
```

Как мне вытащить допустим значение h1?
Делаю вот так, но не выходит:

```
var prodName = $("#productCard" + id + " h1.titleText").text();
```

Comment: если в `id` у вас находится `pCard15`, то у вас получается селектор по `id="productCardpCard15"`, а такого нету

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас опечатка, вы ищите по `id = #productCard`, тогда как у вас у элемента `id =`pCard15`

```js
var id = 15;
var prodName = $("#pCard" + id + " h1.titleText").text();

console.log(prodName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4 productCard" id="pCard15">
  <img class="image" src="ссылка">
  <h1 class="titleText">1243</h1>
  <p class="descriptionText">123</p>
  <p class="priceText">321$</p>
  <button class="btn btn-success changeProduct" id="changeProduct">Change Product</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вытащить текст можно есть два способа в **JS** первый это ниже

**innerHTML**

Второй

**textContent**

Также три способа в **jQuery**

1.**.text();**

2.**.contents();**

3.**.html();**

Пример на чистом JavaScript

```js
let titleText = document.querySelector(".titleText").innerHTML;

console.log(titleText);

let priceText = document.querySelector(".priceText").textContent;

console.log(priceText);
```

```html
<div class="col-4 productCard" id="pCard15">
<img class="image" src="ссылка">
<h1 class="titleText">123</h1>
<p class="descriptionText">123</p>
<p class="priceText">321$</p>
<button class="btn btn-success changeProduct" id="changeProduct">Change Product</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
var prodName = $("#productCard" + id + " h1.titleText").text();
```

вставьте

```
var prodName = $("#pCard" + id + " h1.titleText").text();
```